# Get array of Models from a laravel collection

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Given a `Collection` of Eloquent `Models`, which are `Arrayable`, how can I get an array of those objects?

If I call `->toArray()` on the collection, it gives me a nested associative array, destroying the models.

If I cast it to an array, I get this REALLY odd thing:

```
array:1 [▼
  "\x00*\x00items" => array:1 [▼
    "temp" => HistorySeries {#374 ▼
      #table: "history_series_hse"
      #primaryKey: "id_hse"
      #connection: "mysql"
      +timestamps: false
      <...snip...>
    }
  ]
]
```

Then there's this, but I'm not really liking it (it works):

```
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($coll);
    $property = $reflection->getProperty('items');
    $property->setAccessible(true);
    $array = $property->getValue($coll);
```

Or I could extract it using a foreach loop, but that's ugly. Any nice way?

Comment: Try `$collection->all()`?

Comment: Did you tried [each()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-each) method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Collection` is just a wrapper around a standard array. To get that standard array, call the `all()` method on the `Collection`.

```
// Collection of Item models
$itemsCollection = Item::all();

// standard array of Item models
$itemsArray = $itemsCollection->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to cast to array, instead keep you Collection intact and use high order functions like `map` or `each` to do what you need to.

Ex:

```
$multiplied = $collection->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item * 2;
});

$multiplied->all();
```

You don't specify what you actually need to do with the data so this is just a loose example [from the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-map).

You can't cast to array and keep the model intact, it won't work.

Comment: "You can't get an array and keep the model intact, it won't work." That's incorrect. It's entirely possible to get an array of models out of a collection of models.

Comment: I realize that's not what I meant to say.